# Summing up specific entries in subset group (R programming)

Tags: r

So basically I have this format of data:

```
ID  Value
1   32
5   231
2   122
1   11
3   ...
2   ...
5   ...
6   ...
2   ...
1   33
.   ...
.   ...
.   ...
```

I want to sum up the values with ID '1', but in a group of 5.
i.e. 
In the first 5 entries, there are 2 entries with ID '1', so i get a sum 43,
and then in the next 5 entries, only one entry have ID '1', so i get 33.
and so on...
so at the end I want to get a array with all the sums, i.e. (43,33,......)

I can do it with for loop and tapply, but I think there must be a better way in R that doesnt need a for loop

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do the values always come in multiples of 5? What happens if there are 23 rows? Do just the last three get grouped together?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. The values not necessarily come in multiples of 5. And yes just the last three get grouped together in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new column to reflect the groups of 5:

```
df = data.frame(
  id = sample(1:5, size=98, replace=TRUE),
  value = sample(1:98)
)
# This gets you a vector of 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 3, ...
groups = rep(1:(ceiling(nrow(df) / 5)), each=5)
# But it might be longer than the dataframe, so:
df$group = groups[1:nrow(df)]
```

Then it's pretty easy to get the sums within each group:

```
library(plyr)
sums = ddply(
  df,
  .(group, id),
  function(df_part) {
    sum(df_part$value)
  }
)
```

Example output:

```
> head(df)
  id value group
1  4    94     1
2  4    91     1
3  3    22     1
4  5    42     1
5  1    46     1
6  2    38     2
> head(sums)
  group id  V1
1     1  1  46
2     1  3  22
3     1  4 185
4     1  5  42
5     2  2  55
6     2  3 158
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but why does the value V1 is slightly different to actual value in your case?
e.g. In group 1, there are two ID '1', the sum is 29+35=64, but the V1 is 76...

Comment: @user2341380 Ah, I was accidentally summing over all columns, instead of just the `value` column. It should be fixed now. The example data will be different because I randomly generated it and forgot to call `set.seed()`, but they should match up now.

Comment: oh thank you very much, but I am interested to know what exact mistake you made so that I wont make something like that in the future. So in your original answer, what else was included in the sum?

Comment: For `id` = 1, `group=`, the original answer was summing the `value` column, but also the values for `id` and `group`, so you got 46 + 1 + 1 = 48 (and the error would have got larger and larger as the group number increased). It's now only using the `value` column, as intended.

Comment: thanks..I still has one last question.. now I want to extract the V1 in each group who has id '3'. I tried to use the 'match' and %in% function, but they both have a problem that, if in a particular group has no id '3', then I failed to produce the correct array. How can I tell R to sub V1=0 if there is no id '3' in any one of the group? i.e. I want to produce array :(22,158,....)
Thank you!

Comment: I have also tried something like this:
subset(sums,group==(1:numberofgroup),id==3), but this doesnt work in R apparently..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the job:

```
m <- matrix(d$Value, nrow=5)

# Remove unwanted elements
m[which(d$ID != 1)] <- 0

# Fix for short data
if ((length(d$Value) %/% 5) != 0)
  m[(length(d$Value)+1):length(m)] <- 0

# The columns contain the groups of 5
colSums(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a column to delineate groups, `ddply()` can work magic:

```
ID <- c(1, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1)
Value <- c(32, 231, 122, 11, 45, 34, 74, 12, 32, 33)
Group <- rep(seq(100), each=5)[1:length(ID)]

test.data <- data.frame(ID, Value, Group)

library(plyr)
output <- ddply(test.data, .(Group, ID), function(chunk) sum(chunk$Value))


> head(test.data)
   ID Value Group
1   1    32     1
2   5   231     1
3   2   122     1
4   1    11     1
5   3    45     1
6   2    34     2

> head(output)
  Group ID  V1
1     1  1  47
2     1  2 125
3     1  3  49
4     1  5 237
5     2  1  36
6     2  2  74
```

Comment: Holy crap. Marius beat me to it, with basically the same exact answer.

Comment: His is better though. Mine creates the groups kind of wastefully, and won't work for larger tables (unless you change `seq(100)` to something bigger.)

Comment: I think the identical answers speak to how good `plyr` is at providing you with a model for approaching these kinds of problems. It's a good thing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have the same question as in Marius's answer.. why does the value V1 is slightly different to actual value in your case? e.g. In group 1, there are two ID '1', the sum is 32+11=43, but the V1 is 47..

Comment: Oops. Like Marius, I was summing up all the columns, not just the "Value" column. You can pass a custom function to `ddply` like so: `ddply(test.data, .(Group, ID), function(chunk) sum(chunk$Value))` (since `ddply` divides the dataframe into chunks, this function just takes the sum of each chunk's "Value" column)